# Exist-DB exclude file from transformation

Tags: exist-db

I am currently working on indexing my App. 
Upon following a tutorial, I reached a dead end:

```
err:FORG0001 can not convert '/.../collection.xconf' to xs:integer [at line 65, column 26]
```

I kind of know where the problem is, but I haven't found a solution for it. 
I think that I need to exclude collection.xconf from my function:

```
   declare function app:test($node as node(), $model as map(*)) {
        for $doc in collection(concat($config:app-root, "/data/edition"))
        let $id := replace(document-uri($doc),".*/([^.]*)\.xml", "$1") cast as xs:integer
        order by $id
            return
                 <li class="semanticClassNameFinden" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="{$id - 29}" style="list-style:none;"> Page {$id}v/ {$id+1}r </li> 
    };
```

How can I exclude this file from my function?

I thought about adding sth like `?select=*.xml` or adding `'*.xml'` to the "for-line", but doing so only returns in the function not running. 
Any other hints?

best wishes, 
K

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a file such as `collection.xconf` from the results returned by the `collection()` function, you could a predicate to the function to filter out nodes in the undesired namespace. For example, compare the following two queries:

**Query 1**

```
xquery version "3.1";

collection("/db/apps/eXide")
```

This query should return two documents: one with a `<package>` root element (from `expath-pkg.xml`) and the other with a `<collection>` root element (from the `collection.xconf` file).

**Query 2**

```
declare namespace cc="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0";

collection("/db/apps/eXide")[not(cc:collection)]
```

This query returns only one document: the one with `<package>` root element (from `expath-pkg.xml`). It filtered out `collection.xconf` file.